# NullPointerException occurring infinitely

Tags: java

I want to display list of record from database to output text field. I'm having problem with method with brings record from database. It is causing an infinite loop as it call in constructor of managed bean class. Here is the code.

Constructor of managed bean class:

```
public InterViewDto() throws SQLException {

        User u = getCurrentUser();
        InterviewDao d = new InterviewDao();
        List<InterViewDto> dao1 = d.getCall(u.getEmailAddress());
        setDto(dao1);

    }
```

Method bringing record from database :

```
public List<InterViewDto> getCall(String email) throws SQLException {
        System.out.print("fyc");
         List<InterViewDto> list = new ArrayList<InterViewDto>();

        String job = null;
        boolean exists = false;

        Connection c = null;
        try {

            c = openConnection();

            String query_check = "SELECT *  FROM interviewcall WHERE useremail = '"+email+"' ";
            Statement st = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query_check);

            while (rs.next()) {

                InterViewDto dto = new InterViewDto();
                dto.setDate( rs.getDate("time"));
                dto.setJobtitle( rs.getString("jobtitle"));
                dto.setJobtitle( rs.getString("useremail"));
                list.add(dto);
                System.out.print(list.get(0).getJobtitle());

            }       rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: "bring record from database it is causing infinite loop" - makes no sense to me.  Can you clarify?

Comment: You are creating `new InterViewDto()` inside `getCall`, but you are also calling `getCall` inside the `new InterViewDto()` constructor... is not obvious why there is an infinite loop?

Comment: in console its occuring like loop

Comment: You asked the same question before.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461992/nullpointerexception-occuring-inifnitely

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency.  Your constructor for the DTO reaches out to the database, which in turn creates a new DTO to represent the data loaded from the database, which goes to the database and back and forth until you overflow the call stack.

Quite simply, you have merged two complementary design approaches.

Either your InterViewDto constructor loads data from the DAO or the DAO constructs a new InterViewDto object.  Pick one or the other.

In my opinion, it makes more sense for the DAO to create the DTO objects.  If you want the DTO to delegate to the DAO as a matter of convenience, consider a static method.

```
public class InterViewDto {
    public InterViewDto() {
    }

    ...

    public static fromCurrentUser() {
        return new InterviewDao().getCall(getCurrentUser().getEmailAddress());
    }
}
```

Then change your constructor to be empty.